# Convert seconds to Days, Minutes and Seconds

Tags: c++, date, time, seconds

I've been set the 'challenge' of converting seconds to format as the Days,Minutes and Seconds.

For example: 31600000 = 365 days, 46 minutes, 40 seconds.

```
using namespace std;
const int hours_in_day = 24;
const int mins_in_hour = 60;
const int secs_to_min = 60;

long input_seconds;
cin >> input_seconds;

long seconds = input_seconds % secs_to_min;
long minutes = input_seconds / secs_to_min % mins_in_hour;
long days = input_seconds / secs_to_min / mins_in_hour / hours_in_day;

cout << input_seconds << " seconds = "
     << days << " days, "
     << minutes << " minutes, "
     << seconds << " seconds ";

return 0;
```

It works and comes up with the correct answer but after completing it I looked at how other people had tackled it and theirs was different. I'm wondering If I'm missing something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the things about programming is that there is never just one way to do something.  In fact if I were to set my mind to it, I might be able to come up with a dozen completely different ways to accomplish this.  You're not missing anything if your code meets requirements.

For your amusement, here's a way to format up hours:minutes:seconds under Windows (`elapsed` is a double & represents number of seconds elapsed since... something)

```
sprintf_s<bufSize>(buf, "%01.0f:%02.0f:%02.2f", floor(elapsed/3600.0), floor(fmod(elapsed,3600.0)/60.0), fmod(elapsed,60.0));
```

Answer (score 11):

this seems to me to be the easiest way to convert seconds into DD/hh/mm/ss:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;    

time_t seconds(1641); // you have to convert your input_seconds into time_t
tm *p = gmtime(&seconds); // convert to broken down time

cout << "days = " << p->tm_yday << endl;
cout << "hours = " << p->tm_hour << endl;
cout << "minutes = " << p->tm_min  << endl;
cout << "seconds = " << p->tm_sec << endl;
```

Comment: are you sure? With your code I get that 1641 seconds are equal to days = 0 hours = 1 minutes = 27 seconds = 21 , which seems highly unlikely to me (one hour too much)

Comment: Yes, you're right Wim. You have to use gmtime instead of localtime when converting to broken down time. Perhaps you're in a UTC +01:00 time zone (e.g. CET), where the one hour difference come from.

Comment: ah, didn't think of that one, thank you very much :-) but I am currently using the answer of John Dibling (see above) :
    int hours = floor(totalseconds/3600.0);
    int minutes = floor(fmod(totalseconds,3600.0)/60.0);
    int seconds = fmod(totalseconds,60.0);
    human_readable.sprintf("%01du %02dm %02ds", hours, minutes, seconds);

Comment: @stoycho Thanks for your answer. I was wondering, how do you use your solution  to display also milliseconds ? Cheers !!

Answer (score 7):

I think is the challenge from Stephen Prata's book. I did it as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long input_seconds = 31600000;

    const int cseconds_in_day = 86400;
    const int cseconds_in_hour = 3600;
    const int cseconds_in_minute = 60;
    const int cseconds = 1;

    long long days = input_seconds / cseconds_in_day;
    long hours = (input_seconds % cseconds_in_day) / cseconds_in_hour;
    long minutes = ((input_seconds % cseconds_in_day) % cseconds_in_hour) / cseconds_in_minute;
    long seconds = (((input_seconds % cseconds_in_day) % cseconds_in_hour) % cseconds_in_minute) / cseconds;
    cout << input_seconds << " seconds is " << days << " days, " << hours << " hours, " << minutes << " minutes, and " << seconds << " seconds.";

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> For example: 31600000 = 365 days, 46 minutes, 40 seconds.

Really?

```
$ bc
365*24*60*60 + 46*60 + 40
31538800

365*24*60*60 + 1066*60 + 40
31600000
```

Did you mean "convert the input into days, hours, minutes and seconds, and then discard the hours" or "convert the input into days, total minutes within a day (i.e. can be more than 60), and seconds"?

In the second case I think you should replace the instruction for minutes with

```
long minutes = input_seconds / secs_to_min % (mins_in_hour * hours_in_day);
```

Comment: Yeah I meant to discard the hours however thanks for the reply.

Answer (score -1):

Convert seconds to days, hours, minutes, and seconds; it works perfectly without consuming many resources:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    const int Seconds_Per_Day = 86400;
    const short Seconds_Per_Hour = 3600;
    const short Seconds_Per_Minute = 60;
    int Input_Seconds;

    cout << "Please, enter seconds: \n"; 
    cin >> Input_Seconds;

    short Number_Of_Days = floor(Input_Seconds / Seconds_Per_Day);
    int Reminder_1 = Input_Seconds % Seconds_Per_Day;
    short Number_Of_Hours = floor(Reminder_1 / Seconds_Per_Hour);
    short Reminder_2 = Reminder_1 % Seconds_Per_Hour;
    short Number_Of_Minutes = floor(Reminder_2 / Seconds_Per_Minutes);
    short Number_Of_Seconds = Reminder_2 % Seconds_Per_Minutes;

    cout << "The number of days is " << Number_Of_Days << ", of hours is " << 
    Number_Of_Hours << ", of minutes is " << Number_Of_Minutes << ", and of 
    seconds is " << Number_Of_Seconds << endl;

    return 0;
}
```