# Qt seconds to DD HH SS

Tags: c++, qt4, intervals, datetime-format, duration

using Qt 4.8 how can I print the time in the format DD HH SS? I have the seconds and I want to get back a string in that format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
QDateTime::fromTime_t(seconds).toString("ss hh DD");
```

see http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qdatetime.html#toString

If you want a duration ( your question was really unclear) try something like :

```
QString seconds_to_DHMS(quint32 duration)
{
  QString res;
  int seconds = (int) (duration % 60);
  duration /= 60;
  int minutes = (int) (duration % 60);
  duration /= 60;
  int hours = (int) (duration % 24);
  int days = (int) (duration / 24);
  if((hours == 0)&&(days == 0))
      return res.sprintf("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
  if (days == 0)
      return res.sprintf("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
  return res.sprintf("%dd%02d:%02d:%02d", days, hours, minutes, seconds);
}
```

Comment: Instead of `seconds_to_DHMS`, you could use `toUTC()` here itself:  `QDateTime::fromTime_t(seconds).toUTC().toString("ss hh DD");`

Comment: `QDateTime::fromTime_t()`is obsolete in Qt5 and its use is discouraged. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime-obsolete.html

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the server uptime as seconds, you can use the `QDateTime` class.

```
QDateTime::fromTime_t(duration).toUTC().toString("dd hh ss");
```

Notice the `toUTC`, that's to set the beginning hour to 0. Since you will only be taking the date, hour and seconds, it doesn't really matter if the seconds are not since that date since the year won't be displayed.

Comment: toUTC() is the key step !

Answer (score 0):

You can use [QDateTime::fromTime_t](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qdatetime.html#fromTime_t) :

> Returns a datetime whose date and time are the number of seconds that have passed since 1970-01-01T00:00:00, Coordinated Universal Time (Qt::UTC).

Comment: I think this is not what I need because the seconds are not since that date. It's a server uptime time

Answer (score 0):

What you want to print is a duration of time...not a "moment" in clock time.  QDateTime doesn't do much with durations except computing [secsTo](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qdatetime.html#secsTo) (and [daysTo](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qdatetime.html#daysTo)), and you pretty much have to roll your own printing.

Good news is the math isn't that hard:

[Convert seconds to Days, Minutes and Seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419562/convert-seconds-to-days-minutes-and-seconds)

Although your internationalization of words like *seconds* / *days* / *years* might be a nuisance.  :(

Answer (score 0):

The math is incredibly hard. Days are not 24 hours, they are usually 24 hours but sometimes 23 or 25 (daylight savings time changes) or 24 hours and a second or two (leap seconds). The same problem goes for months (obviously, since differently-sized months are common) years (leap day) and really anything that inherits day's problem by being defined in terms of days (weeks).